# Как определить версию STL?

Tags: c++

Пишу сериализатор. Требуется определить, есть ли в текущей версии STL баг, связанный с работой с денормализованными числами с плавающей точкой, в `from_chars`. ([см. пример](https://godbolt.org/z/TPj7vPrEn))

Пробовал опираться на версию gcc, но при использовании другого компилятора (icx, clang, ...) макрос  `__GNUC__` может раскрываться в совсем другое значение, не связанное с версией используемой STL (а баг, очевидно, находится именной в STL).

На какой макрос можно опереться для определения используемой версии STL?

Comment: `_GLIBCXX_RELEASE`? Еще есть вариант стандартную функцию не использовать, и взять что-то типа https://github.com/fastfloat/fast_float

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, `_GLIBCXX_RELEASE` - то что нужно.